# Sorting Coordinate string in c#

Tags: c#, string, sorting, latitude-longitude

I currently have a list of coordinates that I need sorted.  Each line represents Longitude, Latitude.  I need to sort only on the Longitude.
It is stored in an string array:
string[] coords = fpdp.Coordinates.ToArray();

Here is the original list:

```
**LongLat**
98.63,85.02
43.08,79.07
26.97,70.88
18.8,62.3
13.47,53.5
8.57,44.8
3.58,36.35
-1.63,28.2
-6.93,20.33
-12.12,12.63
-17.17,5.02
-22.63,-2.25
-28.22,-9.43
-34.98,-15.7
-42.67,-21.08
-51.18,-25.62
-60.55,-29.12
-70.7,-31.12
-81.2,-31.18
-91.42,-29.72
-101.02,-26.97
-109.62,-22.85
-117.3,-17.83
-123.9,-11.9
-129.32,-5.05
-133.55,2.47
-136.9,10.3
-140.45,17.78
-144.75,24.98
-148.6,32.53
-152.02,40.37
-155.85,48.28
-160.8,56.27
-165.75,64.48
-172.62,72.78
171.35,80.83
98.93,85.17
```

Here is what I need it to look like.  It is sorted by Large to small for positive numbers, and small to large for negative numbers.  Only focusing on the first longitude coordinate:

```
**LongLat-Sorted**
171.35,80.83
98.93,85.17
98.63,85.02
43.08,79.07
26.97,70.88
18.8,62.3
13.47,53.5
8.57,44.8
3.58,36.35
-1.63,28.2
-6.93,20.33
-12.12,12.63
-17.17,5.02
-22.63,-2.25
-28.22,-9.43
-34.98,-15.7
-42.67,-21.08
-51.18,-25.62
-60.55,-29.12
-70.7,-31.12
-81.2,-31.18
-91.42,-29.72
-101.02,-26.97
-109.62,-22.85
-117.3,-17.83
-123.9,-11.9
-129.32,-5.05
-133.55,2.47
-136.9,10.3
-140.45,17.78
-144.75,24.98
-148.6,32.53
-152.02,40.37
-155.85,48.28
-160.8,56.27
-165.75,64.48
-172.62,72.78
```

How can I accomplish this in code?  Any help would be great.

**SOLUTION:**

I tweaked this to the following, and it's working. Thanks a lot! :)

```
 public class LongLatSort : IComparer
     {
         int IComparer.Compare(Object x, Object y)
         {
             string[] longLatParts1 = Convert.ToString(x).Split(',');
             string[] longLatParts2 = Convert.ToString(y).Split(',');
             var var1 = double.Parse(longLatParts1[0]);
             var var2 = double.Parse(longLatParts2[0]);

             if (var1 > var2)
             {
                 return -1; // flipped for descending
             }
             else if (var1 < var2)
             {
                 return 1;  // flipped for descending
             }
             // secondary sort on latitude when values are equal
             return var1 > var2 ? -1 : 1; // flipped for descending
         }

     }
```

Comment: Can you provide any source code? :)

Comment: You might want to look into using the [`GeoCoordinate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate(v=vs.110).aspx) class

Comment: What's the precise programming problem you're having with what you tried? (And please include your code)

Comment: looks like a candidate for an array of coordinate objects and bubble sort

Comment: @user1666620 You're joking right?

Comment: @juharr if it's  a homework question, and that's what this looks like, then more than likely that is the purpose of the requirements. otherwise i'd use a linq query and do and orderby

Comment: Sorry guys.  Been caught up doing other things.  Just now getting a chance to reply.  No, this is not homework.  This was a question on suggestions for a sort routine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is this data stored?  An array of Strings? or a 2-dimensional array or floats? or an Array of some structure with a lat and long?  I'll assume its an array of LongLat since thats how you worded it.

**EDIT** I realized your subject title said string, so I added a constructor to convert from string to a LongLat.

Your desired result looks sorted descending on Longitude.

**This code is untested, forgive me if it's not 100% but you get the idea.**

```
// This is pretending to be the data structure you are using
public class LongLat {
    private float mLongitude;
    private float mLatitude;

    // constructor from string for convenience
    public LongLat(string longLatString ) {
        string[] longLatParts = longLatString.Split(',');
        mLongitude = float.Parse(longLatParts[0]);
        mLatitude = float.Parse(longLatParts[1]);
    }

    public float Longitude {get; set; }
    public float Latitude {get; set; }
}

// The sorter
public class LongLatSort : IComparer {
    public int IComparer.Compare(object a, object b) {
        LongLat o1=(LongLat)a;
        LongLat o2=(LongLat)b;
        if (o1.Longitude > o2.Longitude) {
            return -1; // flipped for descending
        } else if ( o1.Latitude < o2.Longitude ) {
            return 1;  // flipped for descending
        }
        // secondary sort on latitude when values are equal
        return o1.Latitude > o2.Latitude ? -1 : 1; // flipped for descending
    }
}

// now you should be able to use the sorter something like this?
// though best to not instantiate the Comparer every time but you get the idea
// EDIT: create your array of LongLats from strings first
Arrays.Sort( yourArrayofLongLats, new LongLastSort() );
```

Comment: Yes, it is a List<string> Coordinates.  The string is in the format of Longitude, Latitude.  Thanks.

Comment: The List<string> Coordinates are converted to string[] coords

Comment: Thanks Aaron for this solution.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Just finished tested this, seems to work.

```
class SimplePoint
    {
        public SimplePoint(string coord)
        {
            var coords = coord.Split(',').Select(s => double.Parse(s, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToArray();
            X = coords[0];
            Y = coords[1];
        }
        public double X;
        public double Y;
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return X.ToString() + "," + Y.ToString();
        }
    }

static class LongLatParseAndSort
{
    public static string SortedLongLat(string unsorted)
    {
        return unsorted
            .Split(' ')
            .Select(c => new SimplePoint(c))
            .OrderByDescending(sp => sp.X)
            .Select(sp => sp.ToString())
            .Aggregate((a, b) => a += b);
    }
}
```